# Mocha unit tests not calling function generators within an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have an object containing a number of function* type generators that I'm trying to write Mocha unit tests for. However, Mocha will not call the functions and I'm having a hard time figuring out what the solution is.

Here is some example code:

```
'use strict';

var ctr = {
        fn: function(arg,cb) {
                console.log( 'arg:', arg );
                var err = (arg == true);
                return cb( err, arg );
        }
};

describe( 'Mocha test', function() {
        it( 'should call the function', function(done) {
                console.log('a');
                ctr.fn( false, function(err,data) {
                        console.log('b');
                        if( err ) return done(err);
                        console.log('c');
                        done();
                        console.log('d');
                });
                console.log('e');
        });
});
```

When I run `$ mocha testfile.js` I get this output:

```
  Mocha test
a
arg: false
b
c
    ✓ should call the function (39ms)
d
e
  1 passing (172ms)
```

That's all as expected. However, If I replace "`fn: function(...`" with "`fn: function*(...`", running `$ mocha testfile.js` results in:

```
  Mocha test
a
e
    1) should call the function


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) Mocha test should call the function:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I thought I found the answer with this [Mocha plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-co), but running `mocha -r mocha-plugin-co testfile.js` gives the same result as not specifying it.

I think I need to "make sure the Promise resolves", but it's not clear to me what that means. I'm not [intentionally] using Promises, but the npm package I'm using wants the functions defined in this form.

Is there a simple solution to make mocha work the way I expect here, or do I need to go change all my code to regular functions and hope nothing breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `next()` method on the returned generator like this:

```
describe( 'Mocha test', function() {
        it( 'should call the function', function(done) {
                console.log('a');
                ctr.fn( false, function(err,data) {
                        console.log('b');
                        if( err ) return done(err);
                        console.log('c');
                        done();
                        console.log('d');
                }).next();
                console.log('e');
        });
});
```

In order to user the [blakeembrey/co-mocha](https://github.com/blakeembrey/co-mocha) plugin, you will have to use `yield` in your generators to continue execution.

Comment: Yup, that works. Some more explanation would be helpful though. It appears that function* returns a Generator, which is a special type of iterator. .next() captures the return and any 'yield's from the function*. I don't quite understand why Mocha hangs though, and the MDN article on function* isn't clarifying.

Thanks also for finding and posting the correct module link. I still had a lot of tabs open when I posted that...